# Rails session not persisting on Rails using Android device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a Rails 6.1 app. I store a session variable for excluded notifications. A user can disable a notification and the specific notification is stored in a session variable.

This setup works fine for desktop. However when using opening the website using an Android device the created session cookie does not persist after closing the browser. So everytime a user closes the browser and reopens it, a new session cookie is created.

- The issue is not related to a specific browser and happens on mobile browsers.
- I store other cookies that do persist

The setup is a follows:

**Store session key in controller:**

```rb
session[:disabled_notices] ||= []
session[:disabled_notices] << params[:notice]
```

**Check if notice if notice is excluded from session variable in view:**

```rb
session[:disabled_notices].exclude?(notice_name)
```

**session_store.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_iftf_session', domain: :all
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this problem? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A session cookie is deleted when a browser is closed unless the browser has a session restore feature enabled. That's why they are called session cookies. Not all browsers have this feature enabled.

Try storing this setting in a separate persistent cookie (a cookie with a Max-age attribute set).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_the_lifetime_of_a_cookie

Comment: Hey Scott, thank you for your reply! This doesn't however seem to be the answer. Even if I set a regular persistent cookie the same problem persists:

Example:

    cookies[:disabled_notices] ||= {
      value: '[]',
      expires: 1.year.from_now,
      same_site: "None",
      domain: :al

Works on my desktop browser. But on after closing the mobile browser and reopening it, the cookie is gone.